# Change direction of ionic range slider

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to make use of the ionic range slider to create a filter on stars (rating).

So the user can filter from 0-5 but would like to change the direction of the range slider as the user will filter from the selected rate and above.

So would like to slide from left to right. This indicate that the user will search from 0 to 3.3 but would like to flip the indicating green line.

[image]

As we search in this case above from 3.3 and above. Could somebody help me out on this?

this is the html:

```
<ion-range min="0" max="5" value="5" step="0.1" snaps="true" mode="md" color="secondary"
   [(ngModel)]="rating" (ngModelChange)="ratingFilter($event)">

   <ion-icon size="small" slot="start" name="star"></ion-icon>
   <ion-icon slot="end" name="star"></ion-icon>
</ion-range>
```

and the `ratingFilter()`:

```
ratingFilter(rating) {
    console.log(rating);
    this.rating = Math.round( rating * 10 ) / 10;
    rating === 0 ? this.showAll = true : this.showAll = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **documentation** doesn't provide any way to invert range slider direction.

A quick way would be to transform the slider to 180 degree which will invert it, hence making it move from left to right.

You can add the following css to the slider. I've not tested it but hopefully it would look something like this:

```
<ion-range min="0" style="transform: rotate(180deg);"  max="5" value="5" step="0.1" snaps="true" mode="md" color="secondary"
   [(ngModel)]="rating" (ngModelChange)="ratingFilter($event)">

   <ion-icon size="small" slot="start" name="star"></ion-icon>
   <ion-icon slot="end" name="star"></ion-icon>
</ion-range>
```

Comment: Did you tried it yourself? This will show weird behavior when sliding

Comment: No I mentioned in answer that I didn't try it. but one way would be to invert it using transform property of css. Btw what weird behavior you are seeing?

Comment: We rotate it 180degrees but the range motion stays the same as before so the motion is mirrored.

Same behaviour like this:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-change-ionic-range-slider-to-vertical-orientation/10414/6